# I have a problems with XSLT code

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a little problem in XSLT. I need write something like this:

```
$city1 = substring-after($address, ',')  
$city2 = substring-before($city1, ' -')  
$city = $city2 or $city1 if $city2 empty
```

i already have this

```
<xsl:variable name="city1"   select = "substring-after($adress,',')" /> 
<xsl:variable name="city2"   select = "substring-before($city1,'-')" /> 
<xsl:variable name="city"   select = "normalize-space($city2 or $city1)" />
```

BUT last round doesn't work... How can I fix it?

Comment: Please explain "doesn't work". What is the actual result, and what was the expected result? Also, are you able to use XSLT 2.0? because that would make the solution simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<xsl:variable name="city1" select = "normalize-space(substring-after($address,','))" /> 
<xsl:variable name="city2" select = "normalize-space(substring-before($city1,'-'))" /> 
<xsl:variable name="city">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$city2 != ''">
       <xsl:value-of select="$city2"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:value-of select="$city1"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```